# not able install pip hence pandas also in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, pandas, pip

I'm using ubuntu 15.10 and python 3.4

when `sudo apt-get install python-pip` it gives **E: Unable to locate package pip** and when using `sudo python get-pip.py`it throws an error message as **The directory '/home/username/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/username//.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.** need to install pip for pandas even when installing pandas `sudo apt-get install python-pandas` and numpy directly using`sudo apt-get install python-numpy`throws the same error of **-H flag**

Comment: You need the Python 3 version of pip. AFAIR it's `python3-pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Or to do this manually :

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Refer Official [Document](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for more.